# Chrome Extension Background script: Change Mouse Cursor while loading

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm new in creating chrome Extension.
Currently I want to start a process which takes up to 5-10 seconds. During this period I want to change the Mouse Cursor to loading, that the user recognizes that something is doing.

The chrome extension is started via right-click on images. Afterwards the image is send to an api as base64 code.

During the whole process I Want that the mouse icon is changed to a loading circle, but I can't access the "document.body.style.cursor" object. "document" is not accessible in the background.js file.

Any help here? What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks for any help / suggestions.

Comment: background script won't hace DOM, you cannot use document methods there. You need to send message to the tab (from background to content script), read about message passing [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/). upon receiving the message in content script, you can change the cursor. be sure to send another message from background to content script to revert the cursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sample changes the cursor to wait when an image is selected and changes it back after 10 seconds.

**Note:**

**If you have DevTools open, it won't come back until you move the cursor.**

background.js

```js
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  chrome.contextMenus.create({
    id: "hoge",
    title: "Select image.",
    type: "normal",
    contexts: ["image"]
  });
});

const cursorToWait = () => {
  const style = document.createElement("style");
  style.id = "corsor_wait";
  style.innerHTML = "* {cursor: wait;}"
  document.head.insertBefore(style, null);
};

const restoreCursor = () => {
  document.getElementById("corsor_wait").remove();
};

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(async () => {
  const tabs = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true });
  await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: tabs[0].id },
    function: cursorToWait
  });
  await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 10000));
  await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: tabs[0].id },
    function: restoreCursor
  });
});
```

manifest.json

```json
{
  "name": "hoge",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": [
    "contextMenus",
    "scripting"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Chrome extension Manifest V3, Use the content script and place your mouse cursor in the content.js file.

**Manifest.json**

```
"manifest_version": 3,
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*"],
      "js": ["js/content.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
```

**content.js**

```
document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';
```

And you can use message passing to know the status of the tab:
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/