# Access local files through Google chrome extension, where code paths are not fixed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I need to access the base64 code of images, if a user opens it inside chrome.
Therefore I have created a chrome extension which activates on a right-click on images.
After selecting the context-menu the base64 code is loaded via Url which is the local file path.

```
const getBase64FromUrl = async (url) => {
    const data = await fetch(url);
    const blob = await data.blob();
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob); 
        reader.onloadend = () => {
            const base64data = reader.result;   
            resolve(base64data);
        }
    });
  }
```

And thats the error i got.

> background.js:152 Not allowed to load local resource:
> file:///C:/Users/cbec/Downloads/MicrosoftTeams-image.png
> getBase64FromUrl @ background.js:152
> background.js:152
> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError:
> Failed to fetch
> at getBase64FromUrl (background.js:152:24)
> at background.js:20:31

Happy about every hints / suggestion.

Comment: I don't think **FileReader** can be used without UI.

Comment: Either use the new FileSystem API or enable "Allow file access" in chrome://extensions for your extension.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was an easy one if one knows how chrome extensiosn work :-)

You just have to add in your manifest file the permission that all urls are allowed inside

```
"host_permissions": [
    "<all_urls>"
]
```

see also for more details, for other problem:

[Chrome Extension Background script: Change Mouse Cursor while loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74092709/chrome-extension-background-script-change-mouse-cursor-while-loading/74104851#74104851)